# Conversion to non-scalar type requested for vector object

Tags: c++

I have the following test-code, and I don't understand the cause of an error

```
main.cpp:25:33: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<MyStruct>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<AnotherOne>’ requested
        std::vector<AnotherOne> c = foo();
```

I thought that copy-constructor defined in my `AnotherOne` is enough for implicit conversion to work. How is `vector<>` performing this copy?

```
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct AnotherOne : public MyStruct {
    int g;
    AnotherOne(MyStruct& x):MyStruct(x) { g=0; }
};

std::vector<MyStruct> foo()
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> result = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct a = {3,5,1};
    AnotherOne b = a; // this is fine
    std::vector<AnotherOne> c = foo(); // this is not
    return 1;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/dLozl7RQWpFQ8Xw8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiating a template gives you a whole new type.

For example

```
template <typename> struct T {};
```

will generate a new type `T` for every parameter. Let's say we have two types related like so:

```
struct B {};
struct D: public B {};
```

so `B` is the base class of `D`, and they're convertible implicitly like

```
D d;
B &b = d;
```

but types `T<D>` and `T<B>` have no such relationship:

```
T<D> td;
T<B> &tb = td; // error
```

because each instance of the template is a whole new type.

Now, we could write our template to explicitly enable conversion, like

```
template <typename U> struct T {
  template <typename V> T(T<V> &&);
  template <typename V> T(T<V> const &);
  // assignment etc.
};
```

and either use SFINAE with `std::is_convertible`, or just let compilation fail noisily if `U` and `V` aren't compatible.

But, `std::vector` *doesn't* explicitly do this. All the constructor and assignment operator overloads are [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can do the conversion manually if you want.

Comment: Thank you! I get the error now. For my purposes, I guess it is easier to push_back() all elements to a new vector<>, since this is a one time-thing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `vector<MyStruct*>` if you want ie to work

Comment: it can't and it doesn't work: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nPhB9BuYX0jGGxBm or your answer is missing vital information.